# Routing USB devices to VirtualBox virtual machine when host OS does not have device drivers

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, usb, virtualbox, drivers

I'm considering changing my host OS from Windows to Ubuntu and virtualizing Windows in VirtualBox, instead. But I'm worried that there will be issues with some of my devices, such as my USB devices (e.g. electric piano, Android device) that require driver installation for them to be usable in Windows.

The problem is that those devices don't have drivers for Ubuntu. For them to be usable in an environment where the host OS is Ubuntu and the guest OS is Windows, the USB connections would have to passed through directly to the guest OS, and then the drivers would be installed as usual in the guest OS.

**Is it possible to pass USB connections without drivers from Ubuntu to a guest OS in VirtualBox?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking from personal experience, yes.

An example: I have several devices for which there are not Windows 7 drivers but there are XP drivers. I set up an XP virtual machine, and when I plug one of these devices in, they show up under the USB icon in VirtualBox. I can then attach them and XP recognizes them and installs the proper drivers. The devices work as expected.

My host is Windows 7, but I'm fairly sure that USB passthrough works the same in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks! I just saw this, too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/113061/will-virtualbox-recognise-a-usb-device-if-ubuntu-doesnt-recognise