# Can VirtualBox use a modem that doesn't work on the host?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtualbox, modem

I have a modem which does not work with Windows 7.  Its drivers are for XP.  My computer runs Windows 7.  Is it possible to set up a virtualized Windows XP instance and install the drivers there and use the modem through the virtual XP instance?  Or would this not work because the modem doesn't work on the host machine?

I've tried to do this and it isn't working, but I don't know if it's because the host doesn't support the modem or if I just have it misconfigured.

**Edit:**

The modem is an internal modem ([USR5699B](http://www.usr.com/support/product-template.asp?prod=5699b)).

Comment: The device would only be visible to the virtual machine IF the virtual machine software supported pci devices in my experience there isn't a single product on the market that does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it can't work. A device cannot be passed through unless the host has rudimentary drivers for it.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: You landed in the low quality queue http://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/89910

Answer (score 3):

If you had a USB modem, it would probably work: VirtualBox is able to pass the USB connection directly to the guest OS, so it doesn't matter if there are drivers for the host, [as I've described in my answer to this related question](https://superuser.com/questions/421333/routing-usb-devices-to-virtualbox-virtual-machine-when-host-os-does-not-have-dev/421337#421337).

From 4.1 beta 2, VirtualBox has [experimental support](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=42920) for PCI passthrough; however, it works on Linux hosts only.

So, given that you have a PCI modem and are running a Windows host, I would conclude that it's impossible to use it in the way you desire.

Comment: As an interesting anecdote: I have a TV tuner card that has Windows 7 drivers, an edge case that does not work on Windows 8. It works fine with a VMware Win7 install with USB passthrough, so now I've got a VM dedicated for watching terrestrial TV (and with 'Unity' mode, equivalent to VBox's 'Seamless', I can even have the program *appear* to be running on the Win8 host). It's hackish, but it works.

Comment: @tapped-out - Might want to update your answer to reflect the fact the device isn't a usb device.

Comment: Actually, in his case it doesn't work precisely because there are no drivers for the host. There *must* be host drivers for the device to be passed through. The host still controls the device.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz not true in my case. I have a USB-to-serial adapter which doesn't have Win7 x64 drivers but does have XP x86 drivers; VirtualBox is able to pass it through to my XP guest without drivers.

Comment: @tapped-out: The device that's being passed through is the USB **port**, not the adapter that happens to be connected to it. And the host has drivers for the USB port -- otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ahh okay, I understand now. thanks for the clarification!